# How to extend res.json in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I need to extend res.json so that the response goes out as text with a csrf token eg

```
&&&CSRF&&&{foo:bar}
```

Sails seems to use a different csrf methodology, but I need to do it this way to match the preexisting client side codebase.

Ideally I need to be able to create a new function:

```
return res.jsonWithCsrf({
  foo: bar
});
```

Internally this would call res.json but would wrap the csfr token around the response.

I gather that I need to write a hook but am unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom responses by placing your file in the api/responses directory.

You can see the files that are already there, modify them if you want, or create your own.

If you were to create jsonWithCsrf.js in that folder, then you can access it in the manner you describe above.

`res.jsonWithCsrf()`

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses